# I'd like to toggle the display of an adjacent div element when I click the radio button, with CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes

This is the code, I've tried different attribute selectors with no avail. It important that the  element is inside a div since it simulates the structure in the real website.

```
#AAA:checked ~ #BBB {
    color:red;
}


<div>
<input type="radio" id="#AAA">click
</div>


<div id="CCC">some content</div>
<div id="BBB">some content</div>
```

[Fiddle where I've been experimenting](http://jsfiddle.net/VtDDg/27/)

Comment: While the input is inside the div you have it in it can't affect elements outside it with CSS. Selectors work for descendants & siblings. Not up then down the DOM.

Comment: There's no parent selector in CSS, therefore it's impossible to style the sibling of a parent element based on the style of that parent's child. In this case styling `#CCC` and `#BBB` based on the `:checked` state of the `<input>` is impossible without JavaScript.

Comment: You are probably better off using some Javascript to do this.